# Is it possible to run multiple instances of SQL Server on the same machine

Tags: sql-server

Is is possible to run multiple instances (installations) of SQL Server databases on the same machine (assuming the machine is not virtualized)

Comment: Yes.  It doesn't matter if the machine is virtualized.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can give the installations different names.  I think you have to choose "advanced options" on installation to be able to set the name.

Comment: You can also have multiple instances of the same version of SQL server, each with a different service pack. There can only exist a single unnamed instance, all the other instances have to be named.

Answer (score 0):

yep, they need to be named instances though.  Run the setup but when you get to the instance name - add a new name for the instance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we can use multiple instance of SQL Server of same machine/server.

All instances of the database engine other than the default instance are identified by an instance name specified during installation of the instance.